# has_css? will not find a present id

Tags: ruby, capybara

I am writing a finder for pages with various but finite id's

```
@field = ['name1', 'name2']

def fieldfind
  @field.each do |elem|
    out = elem if page.has_css?(elem)
  end
end
```

HTML

```
<input type='text' id = 'name1'>
```

For whatever reason, I cannot find name1.  I tried find_field? and elem.to_s, but to no avail.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

As Baldrick mentioned, the css locator is not right. However, after correcting that, you would still get a problem with the `@field.each`. This is going to return an array - not an element or the css of the field that exists.

If you want an element that matches one of the css in @field, try:

```
@field = ['#name2', '#name1']
def fieldfind
  matching_css = @field.find{ |elem| page.has_css?(elem) }
  page.find(matching_css)
end
```

Or if you just want the matching css-locator:

```
@field = ['#name2', '#name1']
def fieldfind
  @field.find{ |elem| page.has_css?(elem) }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You missing `#`, the css selector to find element by id. It should be:

```
@field = ['#name1', '#name2']
...
```

Comment: name1, #name1, input#name1  all turn up negative

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
page.find(:css, "input[id=name1]")
```

If that works, go ahead and dynamically add the variable to your code.

I'm suggesting you try to find an element first (rather than just improving your existing `each` block) is perhaps your session object is pointed towards the wrong window or frame.